# Doom emacs dired +ranger not obeying evil-mode

Tags: evil, dired, doom, ranger

I am using doom emacs and in my init file I have (dired +ranger)

The problem is when I open dired, I cannot press tab to select for example. I have first to toggle off evil-mode. If I do, I lose all doom key bindings.

There should be a work around as in regular dired, I didn't have to toggle off evil mode and doom still working!

Answer (score 0):

You could add dired-mode and ranger mode to variable "evil-emacs-state-modes":
(add-to-list 'evil-emacs-state-modes 'dired-mode)

Comment: I think OP wants to use evil in dired with ranger, not switch to emacs state.